# Cannot find module 'apollo-client/gql'

Tags: meteor, npm, apollo

I have below script that was running until now.

```
//script.js
var apollo = require('apollo-client');
var gql = require('apollo-client/gql');
...
```

`$ node script.js` was working fine till now.

All I did was updated `apollo-client` from `^0.1.6` to `^0.3.3`. Post that I get below error whenever I run above command.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'apollo-client/gql' from '/path/to/script'
```

I then rolled back `apollo-client` to `^0.1.6`. But, the error seems to continue. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with publishing of `0.3.3` version of `apollo-client`. The issue has been fixed in `0.3.4`.

Ref: https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-client/issues/186

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var gql = require('apollo-client/npm/gql');
```